# On the continuity of a function

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing

Below is an attempted proof that the map $f\colon [0,1]\to \mathbb{S}^1$ defined as $x\mapsto e^{2\pi ix}$ is continous.

Let $U_1=\{e^{it}\;|\; 0<t<2\pi\}$ an open set of the unit sphere $\mathbb{S}^1$, then $$f^{-1}(U_1)=\{x\in [0,1]\;|\; f(x)\in U_1\}=(0,1]=(0,2)\cap [0,1],$$
therefore $f^{-1}(U_1)$ is open in $[0,1]$.

This prove that $f$ is continous.

> It's correct?

Comment: of course not ${}$

Comment: @mathworker21I understand. So how can I show continuity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(\pi_1\circ f)(x)=\cos(2\pi x)$ and  $(\pi_2 \circ f)(x)=\sin(2\pi x)$ are both continuous (even differentiable), so $f$ is too by the universal property of maps into products.

Comment: Thanks! Another question, please. How can see that $f$ is bijective?

Comment: @JackJ. Every point on the circle has a unique angle $\alpha \in [0,2\pi)$ with the $x$-axis, in radians. $f(0)=f(1)$ is the only pair where injectivity fails.

Answer (score 2):

No, you must show $f^{-1}(U)$ is open for **all** open $U\subseteq S^1$. You have only shown it for **one** such open set.